# Is the Angular 2 @Component syntax part of ES6?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

Can anyone tell me. The `'@'` symbol in front of the imported Component function. Is that ES6 syntax? I've not seen it used on any other non-angular ES6 projects I've looked at.

```
import {Component} from ...
@Component({})
```

[Here is a example](https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/ng2-play/blob/master/src/hello.js)

Comment: Not that I'd know. Can you point to the docs, please? What does it do?

Comment: I also found this... Annotations are a way to add meta information to our existing code. Those annotations are actually not supported by ES6 but have been developed as language extension and are considered by the Traceur transpiler, which is used in this project. We’re not required to use annotations though. As mentioned, those are just transpiled to ES5 and then simply used by the framework. 

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/03/27/building-a-zippy-component-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: No.

The `@` syntax defines an annotation - this was introduced by Angular's [AtScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AtScript), which later merged into [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/). From what I can see, they are similar to annotations in .NET languages.

Annotations are not a part of standard ES6; they are simply a decoration provided by TypeScript. Of note, Angular 2 supports the use of TypeScript annotations, as does Aurelia.

I can't provide a link at the moment, but there are resources that describe the features and language components of ES6 in great detail.

Answer (score 18):

The `@` syntax is part of a new draft for es7 which is currently in stage 1 (proposal stage). They are called decorators.

> Decorators make it possible to annotate and modify classes and properties at design time.

For more information see: https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators

---

Note: you can use decorators, using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/experimental/) by enabling the `optional[]=es7.decorators` (in webpack) or by setting your configuration to `stage:1`

Answer (score 5):

Just for the records, you can achieve the same behavior in ES6 just by translating the TypeScript annotation into the following:

```
import {Component, ...} from 'angular2/core';
export class myAppOrDirective {
    static get annotations() {
        return [
            new Component({
                selector: 'my-app-or-directive'
            }),
            new View({
                template: `<div>Hello!</div>`
            })
        ];
    }
}
```